# How to check if my user is admin

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I have a question how to check in blade if my user is admin.
 I have created 3 tables: users, roles and users_roles. 
 This is how my code looks:

```
  Users table:
  public function up() { 
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('email')->unique();
     $table->string('password'); 
     $table->rememberToken();
     $table->timestamps(); }); }

 Roles table: 
    public function up(){
     Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table){
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('roleName');
      $table->timestamps(); }); }
 Users_roles table:
     public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
            $table->timestamps();  }); }
  And models:
   User model:
    class User extends Authenticatable {
     protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', ];
     public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Roles", "users_roles");
    }  }
   Roles model:
   class Roles extends Model  {
     public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\User");
     } }
```

And now I want to check in blade is user admin,acctualy if 
  roleName in user table = 'admin'? But I don't know how to to that.
  Thank you in advance for helping

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Comment: Something like `$user->whereHas('roles', function($q) { $q->where('roleName', 'admin'); });` - read up on Eloquent relationships. @mkaatman's advice of using the native authorization support is good, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make this check. This is one of them

Add this to the `User` model

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return !! $this->roles()->where('roleName', 'admin')->count();
}
```

Then you can call the `isAdmin` method on user.

```
$user = User::find(1);

if ($user->isAdmin()) {
    // user is admin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
     protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password', ];
     public function roles(){
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles', 'users_roles','user_id', 'role_id');
     }

     public function inRole($rol) {
         $check =  $this->roles()->where('roleName', $rol)->first();
            if($check == "") {
                 return 0;
            }
            else {
                 return 1;
            }
     }  
}
```

//Roles.php

```
class Roles extends Model  {
    protected $table =  'roles';
         public function users(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_roles', 
            'role_id', 'user_id');
         } 
}
```

Now in view template you can check for any role by passing rolename as a parameter
e.g

```
@if(Auth::User()->inRole('admin') == 1) {
     //admin
}
@elseif(Auth::User()->inRole('manager') == 1) {
     //managaer 
}
@else {
     //user 
}
```